# Plot stretches past axis limit in R when using barplot() with ylim argument

Tags: r, bar-chart, limit, yaxis

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot with percents. I have generated some sample data for replication:

```
#Create dummy data (class is table)
one=c(1,1,.9855,1,1,.9956,.9827,.9868,.988,.9701,1,1,1)
zero=1-one
comp=as.table(rbind(one,zero));comp

#Set wanted axis limits
yax=c(max(min(comp[1,])-.1,0),1);yax
```

Now, the following is the resulting plot before I set axis limits using ylim:

```
#Before setting limits looks fine
par(mar=c(5,6,4,5)) #resize margins
barplot(comp,col=c("#3399CC","#CC0033"),main="Proportion of Results",
    yaxt="n",legend.text=TRUE, 
    args.legend=list(x="topright",inset=c(-0.15,.45)))
axis(2,at=pretty(comp),lab=paste0(pretty(comp)*100," %"),las=TRUE)
```

[image]

Then when I add in the ylim argument, my bars stretch past the the limits set.

```
#After setting limits it's messed up
par(mar=c(5,6,4,5)) #resize margins
barplot(comp,col=c("#3399CC","#CC0033"),main="Proportion of Results",
    yaxt="n",ylim=yax,legend.text=TRUE, 
    args.legend=list(x="topright",inset=c(-0.15,.45)))
axis(2,at=pretty(yax),lab=paste0(pretty(yax)*100," %"),las=TRUE) #Show y-axis labels as percent
```

[image]

I would like to cut off and view only the portion of the plot based on my selected limits. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?